# Ionic Angular XMLHttpRequest not working in InAppBrowser

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, drupal, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to update a simple Ionic app from Angular 1 to Angular 8, which basically loads a website with InAppBrowser.

I am using [Capacitor](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/), created a new app from scratch. The InAppBrowser works fine, the thing is that now I have to make a request to the backend(the website that is being loaded in InAppBrowser, which is a Drupal site) to register the push notifications token.

I am trying to do this with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) but it is not working. The backend accepts cookie auth, so basically if I do this request from the same session where I am logged in the website via InAppBrowser this should work, but instead, I am getting the following error:

```
**{"isTrusted":true}**
```

Is there another way of doing this? The old code from Angular 1 had this approach and it was working. XMLHttpRequest did not change much, there is nothing I should change for Angular 8 compatibility.

Any ideas?